# tf.identity doesn't copy value before assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow

I expect the program to

1. copy the old value of `x` with `tf.identity`,
2. assign new value `y` to `x`

But `tf.identity` doesn't keep the old value of `x`.

The `tf.control_dependencies` should require doing step 1 before step 2.

Result:

```
version: 1.14.1-dev20190531
x_before_: 0.0
x_ident_: 1.0
x_after_: 1.0
```

Test:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dtype = np.float32
x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=(), dtype=dtype,
                    initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
y = tf.constant(1, dtype=dtype)

# Copy value of x before assigning new value y to x
x_ident = tf.identity(x)
with tf.control_dependencies([x_ident]):
    assign_op = tf.assign(x, y)

# Run
init_op = x.initializer
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    x_before_ = sess.run(x)
    x_ident_ = sess.run([x_ident, assign_op])[0]
    x_after_ = sess.run(x)

# Check
print("version:", tf.__version__)
print("x_before_:", x_before_)
print("x_ident_:", x_ident_)
print("x_after_:", x_after_)
assert np.allclose(x_ident_, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this problem in the past, and I think you are right, it should work as you expect. Maybe it warrants [filing an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). I don't have a solution as such, but my workaround is to have a useless operation like adding zero:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dtype = np.float32
x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=(), dtype=dtype,
                    initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
y = tf.constant(1, dtype=dtype)

# Force snapshot of x with zero addition
x_ident = x + 0
with tf.control_dependencies([x_ident]):
    assign_op = tf.assign(x, y)

# Run
init_op = x.initializer
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    x_before_ = sess.run(x)
    x_ident_ = sess.run([x_ident, assign_op])[0]
    x_after_ = sess.run(x)

# Check
print("version:", tf.__version__)
print("x_before_:", x_before_)
print("x_ident_:", x_ident_)
print("x_after_:", x_after_)
assert np.allclose(x_ident_, 0)
```

Output:

```
version: 1.14.0
x_before_: 0.0
x_ident_: 0.0
x_after_: 1.0
```